# Arduino, input from BT-Module is stacking and added

Tags: arduino, bluetooth

I wrote an Android App which sends data to an Arduino via Bluetooth. The Connection works fine and is pretty stable. The only thing that bothers me is that the input from the serial connection is not how I would like it to be. This is hard for me to explain but every time I send a new command, the ols command is still in the serial input so that the new input is not recognized by the Code I wrote. Maybe this is just a very dumb issus but I just dont know what I can do to fix it. I will post the Code and the Output here so that the problem is visible.

I am using SoftwareSerial (here as `BTserial`) and it feels like I have to clear the buffer of the connected HC-05 module or the serial buffer and I tried so many other solutions but none of them worked, maybe I just don't understand what the issue is here.

My code:

```
void loop() {

  //Serial.println(BTserial.available());
  if (BTserial.available() > 0) {
    delay(100);
    serialEvent();

    if (stringComplete) {
      Serial.println(inputString);

      int colorValues[3] = {0, 0, 0};

      sscanf(inputString.c_str(), "%d,%d,%d", &colorValues[0], &colorValues[1], &colorValues[2]);

      analogWrite(red, colorValues[0]);
      analogWrite(green, colorValues[1]);
      analogWrite(blue, colorValues[2]);
    }
  }
}


void serialEvent() {
  while (BTserial.available()) {
    // get the new byte:
    char inChar = (char)BTserial.read();
    // add it to the inputString:
    inputString += inChar;

    // if the incoming character is a newline, set a flag
    // so the main loop can do something about it:
    if (inChar == '\n') {
      stringComplete = true;
    }
  }
}
```

```
Serial output

1,2,3

1,2,3
1,2,3

1,2,3
1,2,3
1,2,3

1,2,3
1,2,3
1,2,3
1,2,3

1,2,3
1,2,3
1,2,3
1,2,3
1,2,3

1,2,3
1,2,3
1,2,3
1,2,3
1,2,3
1,2,3

1,2,3
1,2,3
1,2,3
1,2,3
1,2,3
1,2,3
1,2,3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the Serial buffer that you need to clear.  It's the String that's holding the command you read.  You have to clear that out.  The serial buffer gets cleared out as you read the characters from it.

```
if (stringComplete) {
          Serial.println(inputString);

          int colorValues[3] = {0, 0, 0};

          sscanf(inputString.c_str(), "%d,%d,%d", &colorValues[0], &colorValues[1], &colorValues[2]);

          inputString = "";     // Remove old command from inputString

          analogWrite(red, colorValues[0]);
          analogWrite(green, colorValues[1]);
          analogWrite(blue, colorValues[2]);
        }
```